# Why am I getting different results between the two codes?

Tags: java

The first code is my own for an assignment on Lynda.com. The second code is the teacher's answer to that assignment. Besides a few words here and there I haven't been able to find any difference in logic or equations, yet the first code gives out a number as the solution way lower than the solution the second one gives out.

```
public class SimpleCalculation {


public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Declare all variables
// Ask for the house length, width, and height
// Ask for the number and size of windows
// Ask for the number and size of doors
// Calculate total surface area to be painted
double w, l, h;
double numWin, winWidth, winHeight;
double numDoors, doorWidth, doorHeight;
double surfaceArea;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the width, length and height of your house: ");
w = in.nextDouble();
l = in.nextDouble();
h = in.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter the number of windows, width and height: ");
numWin = in.nextDouble();
winWidth = in.nextDouble();
winHeight = in.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter the number of doors, width and height: ");
numDoors = in.nextDouble();
doorWidth = in.nextDouble();
doorHeight = in.nextDouble();
surfaceArea = (w * h * 2 + 1 * h * 2) - (numWin * winWidth * winHeight +
        numDoors * doorWidth * doorHeight);
System.out.println("The total paintable surface area is: "+ surfaceArea);



}

}







public class SimpleCalculation_Final {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double w, l, h;
    double numWin, winWidth, winHeight;
    double numDoors, doorWidth, doorHeight;
    double surfaceArea;
    System.out.println("Please enter the width, length and height of "
            + "the house to be painted");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    w = in.nextDouble();
    l = in.nextDouble();
    h = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of windows, width and height");
    numWin = in.nextDouble();
    winWidth = in.nextDouble();
    winHeight = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of doors, width and height");
    numDoors = in.nextDouble();
    doorWidth = in.nextDouble();
    doorHeight = in.nextDouble();
    surfaceArea = (w * h * 2 + l * h * 2) - (numWin * winWidth * winHeight + 
            numDoors * doorWidth * doorHeight);
    System.out.println("The total paintable surface area is: "+ surfaceArea);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I spotted, is that you have `1 * h * 2`, while the second code has `l * h * 2` (first is a one, a second is a lowercase L).

I haven't checked your entire code, there may be other differences.

Comment: Ugh.  Never use `l` as a variable.  In some fonts you literally can't tell the difference by looking.

Comment: True. Good thing, Github used different colors for number literals :)